# What is wrong with this elastic json query, mapping?

Tags: json, elasticsearch

I am trying to use nested JSON to query DB records. Here is my query -

```
"query": {
"nested": {
  "path": "metadata.technical",
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "term": {
            "metadata.technical.key": "techcolor"
          }
        },
        {
          "term": {
            "metadata.technical.value": "red"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

}

Here is this part in my mapping.json -

```
"metadata": {
      "include_in_parent": true,
      "properties": {
        "technical": {
          "type": "nested",
          "properties": {
            "key": {
              "type": "string"
            },
            "value": {
              "type": "string"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

And I have table that has column 'value' and its content is -

```
{"technical":
    {
     "techname22": "test",
     "techcolor":"red",
     "techlocation": "usa"
    }
}
```

Why I can't get any results with this? FYI I am using ES 1.7. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1):

To respect the mapping you've defined your sample document should look like this:

```
{
  "technical": [
    {
      "key": "techname22",
      "value": "test"
    },
    {
      "key": "techcolor",
      "value": "red"
    },
    {
      "key": "techlocation",
      "value": "usa"
    }
  ]
}
```

Changing your document with the above structure would make your query work as it is.

The real mapping of this document:

```
{
  "technical": {
    "techname22": "test",
    "techcolor": "red",
    "techlocation": "usa"
  }
}
```

Is more like this:

```
{
  "include_in_parent": true,
  "properties": {
    "technical": {
      "type": "nested",
      "properties": {
        "techname22": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "techcolor": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "techlocation": {
          "type": "string"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

If all your keys are dynamic and not known in advance, you can also configure your mapping to be dynamic as well, i.e. don't define any fields in the nested type and new fields will be added if not already present in the mapping:

```
{
  "include_in_parent": true,
  "properties": {
    "technical": {
      "type": "nested",
      "properties": {
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Okay. Then what I should change if the technical key and value are dynamic? And to be able to search by specific key and value in technical property?

Comment: Hmm. But can I make it work with such document - 
{"technical":
    {
     "techname22": "test",
     "techcolor":"red",
     "techlocation": "usa"
    }
} ?

Comment: You'll need to change the query to use the actual field names

Comment: Though this configuration does not work - https://pastebin.com/0uVsFgGw
It finds nothing

Comment: How I need to change query for that kind of document?

Comment: You're searching for `red` while the values are `red1` and `red2`. You can use a `prefix` query instead of `term` to match all red*

Comment: Right, when I try prefix it does not work with such config - https://pastebin.com/t4mJpvHP
It works when I put 
"prefix" : {
                      "value": "red1"
                      
            } 
though

Comment: Also, I don't need to match only red, I would need to match the key too. Imagine I search for from dropdown chosen 'techcolor' and I write value 'red', I would like to get results this.

Comment: I would tell you to go with the first mapping, i.e. only `key` and `value` and then have an array of key/value pairs in your nested array

Comment: Not sure I understood you right, but this does not work. - https://pastebin.com/6iz0av2u
It tells me [nested] failed to find nested object under path [metadata.technical]

Comment: There is no `metadata` field in your sample documents

Comment: What metadata in this case should be? It is table name in my case.

Comment: This is the original - https://pastebin.com/PexSUrWt 
And I am trying to change it to other table that has column value with that json we decided to use -
{
  "technical": [
    {
      "key": "techname22",
      "value": "test"
    },
    {
      "key": "techcolor",
      "value": "red"
    },
    {
      "key": "techlocation",
      "value": "usa"
    }
  ]
}

Comment: Is there any solution for this?